# Gtk python add changing timeout

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

I'm trying to implement a pomodoro timer using Gtk timeouts (in python3). My most recent approach was to call a timeout `GLib.timeout_add_seconds(25*60, self.pomodoro)` and within the pomodoro function, it starts a new timer (the break) `GLib.timeout_add_seconds(5*60, self.prompt_timeout)` and the pomodoro function returns False (to stop the original timer). And prompt_timeout sets a timer for another pomodoro, etc. The idea is the functions set timers to call each other, alternating between a break, and a pomodoro.
But this doesn't work as I intended. Strange things happen, where the timeouts call the same function multiple times at once, and timeouts happen at random when they shouldn't. Could anyone explain why? And is there a better way to do this?
I'm using gi.repository.

```
from gi.repository import GLib

class TaskNotify:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1
        self.pomodoro_length = 25
        self.prompt_timeout()
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(self.pomodoro_length*60, self.pomodoro)

    def pomodoro(self):
        time = 15 if self.count % 4 == 0 else 5
        self.count += 1
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(time*60, self.prompt_timeout)
        return False

    def prompt_timeout(self):
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(self.pomodoro_length*60, self.pomodoro)
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks = TaskNotify()
    GLib.MainLoop().run()
```

Comment: An MCVE would be nice

Comment: Good point. I'll post one a little later when I have the chance. Meanwhile, here's the source I'm referring to: https://github.com/dmulder/pytracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In creating a MCVE, I discovered I'd made a foolish mistake. In the init, I called self.prompt_timeout(), which starts a timer on self.pomodoro, then back in init I create another timer on self.pomodoro. So, the duplicate timers at odd intervals are caused to by creating multiple timers by mistake.

So, the working version:

```
from gi.repository import GLib

class TaskNotify:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1
        self.pomodoro_length = 25
        self.prompt_timeout()

    def pomodoro(self):
        time = 15 if self.count % 4 == 0 else 5
        self.count += 1
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(time*60, self.prompt_timeout)
        return False

    def prompt_timeout(self):
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(self.pomodoro_length*60, self.pomodoro)
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks = TaskNotify()
    GLib.MainLoop().run()
```